# Is “History of Flight” correct when referring only to one specific flight?

Tags: determiners

The National Transportation Safety Board (NTSB) writes incident and accident reports, mostly involving aircraft. In all their reports, there is a section titled “History of Flight.” That section gives background information on the aircraft, route, times, and more. Wouldn’t “History of the Flight” be the correct way to write it?

Comment: Yes, as part of a sentence and not of a title. Acceptable shorthand.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin: Interesting. How is the acceptability of a shorthand determined?

Comment: Yosef means that when something is a title or heading it doesn't need to be a complete grammatical sentence.

Comment: If the report presents background details of recent flights, then "the flight" would be incorrect. An accident investigation wouldn't limit itself to the actual flight, but see if there is a behaviour pattern from which they can draw likely conclusions.

Comment: I'm only surprised that the further condensed/telegraphed 'flight history' isn't used.